# Check a specific file in Google drive folder with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a script to achieve the following. Tried googling few codes but they don't seem to address what I require. And since I'm new to scripts, I'm kind of lost on this.

1. Check name listed in "Column H" in google sheet and find matching file in Google Drive (need to give a path).
2. If matches, display the hyperlink to the file in "Column I"
3. And also the script should check through all the rows in the sheet, and do the above for each row.
4. And stop checking if Column "Column K" has as "Complete"

Thank you in advance.

The code I was trying the modify for this is follows;

````
  var searchFor ='title contains "2013"';
  var names =[];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    names.push(file.getName());
  }
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders(searchFor);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var file = folders.next();
    names.push(file.getName());
  }
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    Logger.log(names[i]);
  }

}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. Feel free to change the size range of column H ('H2:Hx') :

```
  function myFunction() {
  
  var folderId = '#FolderId';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
  var extension = '.xlsx';
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  var RowSize=sheet.getRange('H:H').getValues().filter(String).length; //calculate max value of rows
  
  var file_name=sheet.getRange('H2:H'+RowSize).getValues()
  var file_checker=sheet.getRange('K2:K'+RowSize).getValues()
  
  for (i = 0; i < file_name.length; i++) {
  
    if (file_checker[i][0]=="Complete"){break;}  
    
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(file_name[i][0]+extension)
  
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next(); 
      var file_url =  childFile.getUrl() 
      sheet.getRange(i+2,9).setValue(file_url);
  } // while

} //for
  
} // function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I set this to a range without giving as H1:H20 etc., can I use H:H ```var file_name=sheet.getRange('H2:H11').getValues()```. In which line does the 4th requirement I mentioned above handled?

Comment: Can the code be set to match the name without file extension? I tried and the cell needs to have the name with file extension. And is it possible to match the name after combining names in Column G & H?

Comment: @Spear I adjusted the code to calculate automatically the size of the column H. You don't need to specify the end row of the range. I start from H2 because I have a title on H1.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much @Marios. Really great. I was searching for this for like 6-7 hours could not get it done. You are a saviour. How can I do, to stop the function from checking if Column "Column K" has a word as "Complete"? And how to search file name without file extension? And Combine names in two columns for the file name search?

Comment: And if I'm using a time-trigger for this function, I need to change the Active sheet?

Comment: I added your 4th requirement. You don't need a file extension to search for the file. You need to specify the name exactly as it appears in the folder.

Comment: For example if the name of the file is "testfile" then you need to enter in the cell "testfile". If it is "testfile.xlsx" then you need to enter "testfile.xlsx" in the cell. In order to combine names you can simply add them. Just include one more column like : var file_name2=sheet.getRange('A2:A'+RowSize).getValues() and then add the two file names like : file_name[i][0]+ " " +file_name[i][0] so you get a space in between the names. Please if you have more questions you need to ask them in a different post. Please accept this answer if it answers your initial requests.

Comment: I need to search for the name without the extension. My sheet contains without extension and the drive file contains with extension. So trying to search without considering the extension. Apologies for troubling you on this.

Comment: what is the extension you want do add?

Comment: The files could be in any extension, like .txt / .pdf / .docx/ .xlsx. So that's why I'm trying to avoid the full file name with extension.

Comment: then you can only search for the name of the files to get the extension of each file. That is the only way. But please post that in a separate post: How to get the name of the files under a folder? Please accept this answer and ask the new question on a different post.

Comment: Sure will do that. Thank you.